# array into variable

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Say I get `{1,2}` from function `f(a,b)` (it doesnt matter what `f` is/does), and I want to store it into `int s[2]`. How would I do it? It seems that I can't just do `int s[2] = f(a,b)`, and I can't separate the output of `f`, since there is no variable to get the values from. `f(a,b)[0]` does not work.

Comment: How are you getting `{1,2}` from `f`?  You can't return an array...

Comment: What return type does `f()` have?

Comment: What is the signature of `f`? Or at least, what is `f`'s return type?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what exactly `f` returns. You can't simply `return {1, 2};`, so it must be returning something else. Is it a decayed pointer to an array? An `std::vector`?

If it's a pointer, get the pointer returned and then assign the values.

```
int* p = f(a, b);
s[0] = p[0];
s[1] = p[1];
```

If `s` was bigger than two elements, then it would be better to use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`:

```
int* p = f(a, b);
std::copy(p, p + 2, s); // where 2 is the size of the array.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `std::array` array wrapper instead:

```
std::array<int, 2> f(int, int);

std::array<int, 2> result = f(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

To return two things from a function, I prefer `std::pair`:

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, int> f()
{
    return std::make_pair(1, 2);
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> p = f();
    int s[2] = {p.first, p.second};
}
```

If the array already exists, you can make assignment even easier via `boost::tie`:

```
    boost::tie(s[0], s[1]) = f();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could copy it, as in ***memcpy( dest, f(1,2), size )***.

Or you could just return a ***struct***.  It's an old trick to wrap an *array* inside a *struct* to easily copy it via *operator=()*.  E.g.:

```
struct Foo { int a, b };
Foo f(int, int);
int main()
{
   Foo myF = f(1,2);
}
```

The *struct* wrapping becomes useful later on, when your code evolves and you decide to return a third value.  Being a *struct* means you can make it a backward compatible change and avoid changing as much other code...

Comment: Liked the second part of using `struct`. Did not like the `memcpy` part.